# Can you created a middleware for websockets in asp core 6?

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-middleware

So, I have a system where a client will create a web socket connection to my dot core 6 application. which works fine.

But now after some time, I need to manipulate the data that the serve ends up getting, but I’m not able to upgrade the clients code, the only thing I can change, is the URL the client is connecting on. so, what I want to do instead, is simple, make a new system, the client will then connect to this, and then I can manipulate the request in the new system, before sending the request to the server. I want to do the same with the response.

I succeed in catching the socket in the "middleware" but when I try to forward it to the server. it crashes.

Anyone knows if a system. or pattern that would be good practices for this. or even a sample somewhere I could learn from?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you share relate code about `try to forward it to the server. it crashes`?

Comment: If I don't misunderstand your question, I think after you accept data and manipulate it in new system, You can send a httpclient with the data to the old system and get the response, Then you can return the response in new system via websocket without  forwarding websocket.